# Should RedisMqServer/RedisMqHost be configured once per application?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, servicestack

I have a web app and a background service that processes messages from Redis. However, I'm unsure as to whether or not the web application's `RedisMqServer` should be configured as a singleton (I'm using Ninject as my IoC container). Each request that comes is will need to send messages to the background service (one-way), but I'm not sure it it should be instantiated per-request or per-application.

I was thinking that the container would be configured like this:

```
var clientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager();
var mqHost = new RedisMqHost(clientManager);

Bind<IMessageProducer>()
    .ToMethod(_ => mqHost.MessageFactory.CreateMessageProducer())
    .InRequestScope();
```

Or maybe the `RedisMqHost/RedisMqServer` isn't necessary when the messages are one-way? Therefore, reducing the configuration to:

```
var clientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager();

Bind<IMessageProducer>()
    .ToMethod(_ => new RedisMessageProducer(clientManager))
    .InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to register the `IMessageService` if your services don't need access to the host directly. But if you do end up using it, then Yes it should be registered as a singleton.

The only thing that needs to be registered is `IMessageFactory`. In this case **RequestScope** is the same as Ninject's default **TransientScope** since if it's being used, it'll only ever be resolved once per request, in your Service class.

The `IMessageFactory` is used in the base [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L81) to lazily load a `IMessageProducer` so you can publish a message in your services with:

```
base.MessageProducer.Publish(new RequestDto());
```

Note: You're using `RedisMqHost` in code which process **all** messages on a **single** background thread. Changing to use `RedisMqServer` will create a background thread for each message type, allowing processing of different messages to happen in parallel.

Comment: Awesome - you're the exact person I was hoping to answer this question. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you answered after I edited the question, but do you think manually creating the `RedisMessageProducer` is better than using the factory? Or does it not matter since this is exactly what the MessageFactory does (I looked at the source)?

Comment: You should always try to avoid bindings to concrete type constructors in code if possible (so always use a factory if it's available). This also highlighted a mistake, you should register `IMessageFactory` instead of `IMessageProducer` - I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that I'm not using ServiceStack for the web application, it's an MVC3 app (therefore `Service` doesn't apply to my case). So, does [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/4126884) make sense? Or would you still instantiate the `RedisMqServer/RedisMqHost` and call the factory like you did in your example?

Comment: Yeah a request-scoped `IMessageProducer` works as well, tho I prefer using well-defined factories myself.

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks for being so helpful and writing an awesome framework!

Comment: np - glad you're finding it useful :)